# Specify Origin network interface for Ping in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, ping

Is there a way to specify the origin Network Interface/IP address when creating a Ping object in .NET?

For example, `ping` utility in windows allows you to do the following, where `10.32.99.113` is the IP of the source network interface on my system.

```
ping -S 10.32.99.113 google.com
```

Comment: I don't think you can, you will need a third party component.